# Why does QGIS algorithm 'Join attributes table' change the types of the shapefile attributes?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

In QGIS 2.18.9...

I have a shapefile with two attributes 'ID' and 'POP', each of which is of the integer type.

I have a CSV file loaded as a delimited, text-only table layer with two attributes 'ID' and 'EMP', each of which is of the integer type.

I use the standard QGIS algorithm 'Join attributes table' to join the table to the shapefile based on the common attribute 'ID'.

The join executes as desired, except that:

1) I can only get an output shapefile if I choose to create a temporary output layer instead of specifying a file name and location for it to save to

2) in this temporary output shapefile, the two attributes from the original shapefile are now of the text/string type instead of the integer type even though the two attributes from the joined table are still of the integer type

Answer (score 2):

In order to join the data with the same data type, you need to create a **CSVT** file with the *same CSV filename* where you indicate the column data type inside then place the **csvt** in the same directory.

**Example:**
*my_data.csv*
1,"voldemore,100

*my_data.csvt*
"Integer", "String", "Integer"

**Reference:**
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html

Comment: Yes, I did write a CSVT file and store it in the same folder as the CSV file.  The CSV file loads correctly - i.e. with the correct data types.The issue is that the type of the attributes 'ID' and 'POP' in the original shape file changes from 'integer' before the join algorithm to 'string' after the join.